# Mysql PHP, Retrived string contains apostrphone cant replace

Tags: php, mysql, str-replace

I have some records on my table and as I can see it on PHPMyAdmin it contains apostrophe like this:

```
Brazil’s ‘car wash’
```

When I make a query and echo them on web page without any header these apostrophes appear as question marks like this:

```
Brazil�s �car wash�
```

but with this header:

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1");
```

they appear correctly.

Now the problem, **I cannot replace them using this code:**

```
$title = str_replace('’',"",$title);
$title = str_replace("‘","",$title);
```

How can I replace those apostrophes if str_replace not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This indicates your data is stored in ISO encoding, while the default encoding of your webpage might be UTF-8 or something else. Why replace them? You could convert your data to UTF-8 prior outputting or change the whole site encoding to ISO. But I would always prefer UTF-8.

You can convert to UTF-8 with `$title = utf8_encode($title)`.

Comment: Thanks. While I mark this as answer because it solved my problem but I have a follow up. this code removes the apostrophe all together. what if I want to replace it with something else?